# consuming response in jersey in java

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I have a model class with an `@XmlRootElement` annotation. I want to know how I can receive it as a response in a function.

My model class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SurveyAnswers {

    List<Long> Q_id;
    Date date;
    String SurveyType;
    List<Answers> answers;
    float versionid;
    String mac;
    String remarks;

    // getter and setter here

}
```

I have previously used `MultivaluedMap<String, String>` for all my string based responses, but here it is a different structure to receive.

Answer (score 0):

If your `SurveyAnswers` class is the only POST param then you can simply do like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/postpath")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response handlePostRequest(SurveyAnswers surveyAnswers)
```

Follow this sample to learn more about consuming custom classes as the input params to jersey webservices:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Comment: does my "Answer" class need to have a Xmlrootelement annotation ? It contains a field List<String> ans